# memory comsumption of a program in c++ using graphs

Tags: c++, graph

I made an algorithm that uses graphs and im using an adjency list and algorithm works fine the problem is that it consumes a lot of memory and i defined my graph like this:

```
typedef struct vertex
{
    int id;
    int type;
    int d;
    vector<int> adj;
} vertex;

graph = vector<vertex>(n, vertex());
```

for some reason after i debug it looks well but it consumes too much memory, is it because im using a loop were i use long unsigned int, or because im using vectors or because the graph is looking in too may adjencies?

Example of loop using long unsigned int:

```
int output(vector<vertex> &g)
{
    int l = 1;
    int aux = 1;
    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < g.size(); i++)
    {
        if (g[i].type == SOURCE)
        {
            if ((aux = BFS_colorless(g, g[i])) > l)
                l = aux;
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

Btw is there a more efficient way of implementing a graph other than i did?

Comment: Yes. You don't have to define a `struct` for representing a graph. You can do it using this `vector<int> adj[n]` where `n` is the number of vertices in the graph

Comment: btw what are you trying to implement using the function `output()`. It is not clear from the implementation you shown

Comment: well actually what im trying to do is build a graph from a file a do a modified bfs on its source vertexes, i didnt include every function ive used because it would probably be too long to read and the output is the result of the modified bfs

Comment: How many nodes do your graph has? How many edges per node in average?

Comment: I don't know but I already fixed the problem thanks everyone for the help